# postgres+JDBC: fire trigger with non autocommit transaction

Tags: postgresql, trigger, transaction, jdbc

i have a jdbc client that make an two INSERT query on database whitout autocommit, and a trigger on database that fires when a insertion is done on a certain table

```
public foo() throws MyException {
    String INSERT1 = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?,?)";
    String INSERT2 = "INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(?)";
    try {
        Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstm1 = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT1);
        PreparedStatement pstm2 = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT2);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

        pstm1.setString(1, "string1");
        pstm1.setString(2, "string2");
        pstm1.executeUpdate();

        pstm2.setString(1, "string3");
        pstm2.executeUpdate();

        conn.commit();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new MyException("foo error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                throw new MyException("foo error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
            }
            new CloseConnection(pstm1, pstm2, null, conn).closeAll();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new MyException("foo error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

and the trigger looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_procedure() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $my_trigger$
DECLARE new_field VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN
    new_field = NEW.field;
    --field is a column of table 2
    --retrieve some data from table1 and table2 then execute some insert on 
    --another table
COMMIT;
END;
$my_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON table2
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_procedure();
```

now, everytime I execute the jdbc code, the insertion always fail. With some debug with println() I see that my code fail on

```
pstm2.executeUpdate();
```

but no exception was caught. I think it's a trigger problem that try to start execution when my jdbc transaction is not yet committed, in fact, the error on postgresql is

> record new is not assigned yet

There's a way to fix it (start trigger when my trasaction is committed)?

Comment: Regarding your last question, you are after deferrable triggers.  Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtrigger.html) says: _'This can only be specified for constraint triggers.'_  You have to put the logic of your trigger procedure into a 'normal' procedure and call it from your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is fired for each statement not for each row. In statement level triggers you can not access the `new` and `old` records.

You need to change your `create trigger` to create a row-level trigger, rather than a statement level trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON table2
  FOR EACH ROW -- this is the change
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_procedure();
```

Triggers are always executed in the same transaction as the triggering statement.

Comment: still doesn't work. Now i obtain a new error. The error is on query that fires trigger. Log told:
cannot begin/end transaction in pl/pgsql. the context is line of trigger contains COMMIT command, and the statement that throw error is the insert command that fire trigger.

Comment: @giozh you can't issue a `COMMIT;` inside a function.  Just like `BEGIN;` and `ROLLBACK;` - all these are supposed to throw an error.

Comment: You cannot (and should not!) mess with the transaction established by the firing query. Committing inside a trigger seems like a very strange (if not wrong) thing to do. Any change done in the trigger *will* be committed by the transaction in which the trigger was fired.

Comment: ok, now it works. But if for some reason my jdbc client catch exception and call rollback after the trigger were fired, the trigger will execute the same (leaving database in inconsistent state) or not? because it looks like that triger doesn't wait commit command of jdbc.

Comment: Again: anything that is done inside the trigger is part of the current transaction (the one that is active when the trigger is fired) and thus will be committed or rolled back together with that transaction. That's the whole purpose of a transaction.